# Gcloud storage: getImageServingUrl usage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

My App Engine app serves images from Cloud Storage, I get images' urls with  `getImageServingUrl`:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/images

I need to save image urls in the database. I am now wondering how I should save the urls, by either:

- saving gs://BUCKET/PATH and every time when the image must be displayed,
  request the servingUrl.
- saving the servingUrl

As I can understand, Google Cloud storage distributes it's files over the world and works like a CDN. I haven't dived much into how this works but my guess is that the servingUrl could return different results depending on the visitor's location? (if I would pass that as an argument somewhere). If so, I would have to already build my app using getImageServingUrl on every view? Or is this guess wrong, meaning the servingurl is static and the same all over the world?

My other concern is that calling getImageServingUrl all the time requires extra processing time because of communication with the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/PATH should work for any application that wants the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Thanks, I did not see this url before, however I cannot access my bucket contents with it. Maybe that only works for buckets that are fully public? I do want to use the 'secret' url that is generated with getImageServingUrl as the images are private to each user's account. My concerns are the points I noted

Comment: That URL will work for any individual object that is publicly viewable. Its bucket does not need to be public.

Comment: You're right, sorry, the item shared needs to be marked as publicly viewable first. Only then will the URL start working. Not sure if there's an API for that. Here's a website that mentions it - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_sharingdata